# Merge two IEnumerables in elegant way

Tags: c#

I have two IEnumerable variables, both can be null. I need to merge them into a single list. Here is direct approach.

```
var ienumerable1 = GetEnumerable1(); 
var ienumerable2 = GetEnumerable2(); 

if(ienumerable1 != null){
   if(ienumerable2 != null){
      return ienumerable1.Union(ienumerable2);
   }
   return ienumerable1;
}
else{
   return ienumerable2;
}
```

Is there a more elegant way in less lines of code to do this?

Comment: And by "merge", what *specifically* do you mean?

Comment: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.union(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Why is this not considered to be elegant? I think there is no shorter and easier way doing this.

Comment: What defines 'more elegant'?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You started out with -100 elegance points by writing code that returns null enumerators.  Whatever you do is just lipstick on that pig, you'll never get it above 0.  Fix the real problem, an enumerator that returns nothing is functionally equivalent to a null enumerator.

Comment: @HimBromBeere less lines of code is more elegant.

Comment: @Ask Roberts answer is one line long, did you think that was more "elegant" than my 3 line answer?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Both are shorter than question, yours is more readable.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [improving working code](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/code-review/info), which is generally off-topic for StackOverflow. This question may be more appropriate on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @HenryKeiter They closed question there because it is topic for StackOverflow and not really a "working code" sample ;)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just check for null and assign `Enumerable.Empty` if it is null. This can be done in one step with the [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) `??`

```
var ienumerable1 = GetEnumerable1() ?? Enumerable.Empty<WhateverType>();
var ienumerable2 = GetEnumerable2() ?? Enumerable.Empty<WhateverType>(); 

return ienumerable1.Union(ienumerable2);
```

Comment: You could write your own union extension that does this replacement under the covers.

Answer (score 0):

```
   var ienumerable1 = GetEnumerable1(); 
    var ienumerable2 = GetEnumerable2(); 
    return ienumerable1 != null
                    ? (ienumerable2 != null ? ienumerable1.Union(ienumerable2) : ienumerable1)
                    : ienumerable2;
```